# Programmatically compare Two java Source files in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on the Eclipse plugin where I want to compare two java source code. I am able to compare the two java code in text level. I have referred 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F for comparing two codes.
My code looks like:

```java
    CompareItem ancestor = new CompareItem(file1);
    left = new CompareItem(file1);

    right = new CompareItem(file2);

    node = new DiffNode(null, Differencer.CONFLICTING, ancestor, left, right);

    return node;
```

My Compare Dialog looks like (figure 1):
[image: Figure 1]

How can I compare two files in source code level so that I get something like (figure 2):
(with all the java formats.)
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: I don't think this can be done easily as most of the code that does this is internal to the JDT plugin and is not an official API. You can look at `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.compare.JavaCompareAction` to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. I wrote a class that implements ITypedElement.
Overriding the getType() method of ITypedElement interface and returning "JAVA" does my work.

My class looks like the following:

```
public class CompareItem implements IStreamContentAccessor, ITypedElement, IModificationDate, IEditableContent{

    private File content;

    public static String newContents;

    public CompareItem(File left ) {
        content = left;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "JAVA";
    }
..}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcTk1.png)